# How to load the HTML, containing AngularJS, using RESTful access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

When NOT using AngularJS, I create a web site that responds to /mysite/users . It returns an HTML page with user records filled within a table-like display.

I wish to try an AngularJS approach.  I somehow load the web page, and that page's onload() calls /mysite/users, which returns merely a JSON list of users.

The "somehow" part is what bothers me.  So far I'm reduced to first calling /mysite/showUsers.  This downloads the HTML page which then itself calls /mysite/users.

Likewise, when editing with AngularJS I think I'll have to call /mysite/userEdit/1 which on load calls /mysite/user/1.

I think I'm missing something.  Can I get a clue?
Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had trouble describing what I want to have happen.  Perhaps it is because it goes against the grain of Angular.

My server responds to /user/1 with the JSON for user #1.  For the browser to deal with it, I must have a web page already there that can display this JSON.  Chicken and egg style, how do I get this edit web page into the browser?  My classic example is using /user to list the users and having a link on each user to edit it, such as "/SOMETHING/1".

In the meantime, I've decided to go with /user/edit/1.  That will cause the server to render an HTML file, using server-side scripting to insert a phrase that on window.onload() fills the skeleton HTML with the result of /user/1.

Thanks, Collin, for replying.

Comment: I implemented /user/edit/1 to fetch an HTML page.  In its onload event it calls /user/1 to fill the fields.  All is OK. I then added /user/list to load a search page HTML which then calls /user to fill it.  Not good.  This is interpreted as "get a user with id=list".  I'm reduced to /users/list and /users.

Comment: I'm a stubborn person.  I found a way to make thing work with /user/list, etc.  In the express.Router the sequence you enter your routes is the sequence in which the program tries to satisfy them.  I can get the /user/edit or /user/list to work if I place them very first in line, with /user/edit/:id following.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, the AngularJS approach is not to load pre-rendered HTML from the server, but instead load a list of JSON *data* and rely on AngularJS [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to populate the DOM client-side.

A concrete example in your case would be a page which loads an Angular module that fetches a JSON list of users from `/api/users`, and leverages the `ng-repeat` directive to populate the data into the page right in the visitor's browser. [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/) I found that illustrates how you'd accomplish this.

It's all a matter of where the data gets inserted into the HTML; It can happen on the server-side or the client-side, and Angular favors the latter. (This is not to say you *can't* load pre-rendered HTML from the server, but you would be working against the way AngularJS is designed to be used.)